# field extension $F\subset E$ with both separable and inseparable elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Can someone please give me an example of a field extension $F\subset E$
such that E\F has both separable and inseparable elements?

if $F(\alpha)$ is a simple extension of F, and if $\alpha$ is separable... are all elements of $F(\alpha)$ separable?

thanks

Comment: HINT: All elements of $F$ are separable over $F$. So separable elements always exist.

Comment: Of course, but my intention was for elements of the larger field

Comment: Well, add to an inseparable extension a separable element, and you are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, for a field extension $F \subset E$ which contains separable as well as inseparable elements, simply adjoin such elements.

For an explicit example, let $p$ be a prime and $F=\mathbb F_p(t)$ the field of rational functions over the finite field $\mathbb F_p$. (You need an infinite field of positive characteristic to find inseparable extensions.) If $q$ is any prime then the polynomial $f_q = x^q - t \in \mathbb F_p(t)[x]$ is irreducible by an application of Gauss' Lemma and the Eisenstein criterion. Looking at $f_q'$, the polynomial $f_q$ is separable if $q\ne p$ and inseparable if $p=q$.
So let $E =F(\alpha,\beta)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $f_p$ and $\beta$ is a root of some $f_q$ for $q \ne p$.

A field extension $F \subset E$ is called *separable* if every element of $E$ is separable over $F$. As you suspected, one has the following.

**Theorem** Let $F\subset E$ be a field extension, such that $E=F(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ with all $\alpha_i$ separable over $F$. Then the extension $F \subset E$ is separable.

To prove this, one characterizes separability by means of the *separability degree*, and uses a result about the extension of homomorphisms to simple extensions. Most textbooks covering separable field extensions should contain a proof of this. See, for instance, Lang, *Algebra*, Chapter V, Theorem 4.4.